# Update em tabela com campo de data

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Olá! Preciso fazer um update em uma tabela. Tenho uma espécie de chat no banco, onde ele grava a hora que a conversa foi iniciada, e deveria gravar a hora em que terminou.

Porém, antes de eu implementar o código que gravaria no banco a hora de final, ela foi ficando nula ao passo que eu testava. Então, preciso fazer um update na tabela para substituir estes campos.

O problema é que eu tenho muitos registros de atendimento com final `NULL`, e preciso fazer um `update` baseado no dia daquela conversa. Abaixo segue um exemplo de `select` da tabela `CHAT`: `select * from CHAT where HR_FIM is null`

```
   ID     NOME                HR_INI                             HR_FIM 
   --     ------------        -----------------------            -----------------------
    4     Elisa               2015-04-10 17:39:50.875            NULL  
   13     Jorge               2015-04-10 18:08:33.958            NULL
   18     João                2015-04-10 18:34:44.794            NULL
   23     Sergio              2015-06-28 16:33:25.357            NULL
```

Não consigo fazer um `update` porque, como eu precisaria colcar valores exatos para determinados dias, não poderia simplesmente dar um `where HR_FIM is null`. Tentei fazer umas conversões que achei na internet, e também não funcionou.

Grato.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rapaz, são tantos registros assim? Porque eu te sugeriria fazer um `UPDATE CHAT SET HR_FIM = "data" WHERE ID="id" and HR_FIM IS NULL` .
Ou seja, manualmente para cada ID que possui HR_FIM nula.

Mas tira uma dúvida, esses valores são só para testes?

Porque outra solução seria fazer um UPDATE com a hora atual do sistema, onde todos os HR_FIM forem nulos. Porque garantiria o  preenchimento desses valores nulos, e de quebra com datas posteriores à HR_INI.

Comment: Sim, são para testes. Mas o cliente é extremamente exigente, parece que querem como massa informações extremamente próximas à realidade. Não aceitariam um valor tão alto, porque é uma simulação de chat real. Mas agradeço a sugestão, acho que vou fazer isso mesmo. Como seria esse update com a hora do sistema?

Comment: pode deixar, já consegui. Obrigado, @Ivan !